# Printed text affecting makeshift box around text

Tags: python, printing

I'm trying to print the following text to the screen where a random number for die1-die3 are generated from 1-12 and the third line where the variables are printed the "|" doesnt line up to make a rectangle sometimes and can't find a fix when googling it.
P.S I am not wanting to use matplotlib.
Kind regards, Frozzle

```
def display_dice(die1,die2,die3):
    print("Dice rolled:")
    print("+-------------------------------------+")
    print("|    Die 1    |         |    Die 2    |")
    print("|    ",die1,"      |   ",die3,"   |    ",die2,"      |")
    print("+-------------------------------------+")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prettytable](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/) for example:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def display_dice(die1, die2, die3):
    t = PrettyTable(['Die 1', '', 'Die 2'])
    t.add_row([die1, die3, die2])
    print(t)
```

Output:

```
>>> display_dice(1, 2, 3)
+-------+---+-------+
| Die 1 |   | Die 2 |
+-------+---+-------+
|   1   | 3 |   2   |
+-------+---+-------+

>>> display_dice(5, 12, 743)
+-------+-----+-------+
| Die 1 |     | Die 2 |
+-------+-----+-------+
|   5   | 743 |   12  |
+-------+-----+-------+
```